# The SSL green padlock does not display

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I have recently installed a SSL certificate on my site but the green padloack wouldn't show up.

I'm using Chrome, and it only displays when I go in incognito mode.
When I access my site in normal mode I can see the green padlock flashed before it went to the question mark.

Please help me fix this issue.

Comment: what is the site url

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have successfully installed the SSL Certificate ...

Have you checked all of the links on your page(s)?  If a page includes a `http://` rather than `https://` link, the SSL Padlock would unlikely show.

If you are using Google Chrome, right click on your site and select 'Inspect'.  This will generate a 'window' on your screen.  Look through the Tabs, within this window, and select 'Security'.  Here, Google Chrome will indicate whether a page is secure or no.  Ie ... Whether the SSL Certificate is valid and trusted or not.  If it is not, it will highlight the concerning URLs.

In the even a URL is identified as insecure, simply go back to your website to find the link and replace the `http://` prefix with `https://`.

Refresh the page and the issue should now be resolved.  Unless, there is an alternative issue of course.

You can also check for `http://` entries by right clicking on your page to view the source code and then select 'CTRL + F'.  Then search for `http://`.